# Store undetermined data in Cassandra table

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I am doing research in different NoSQL dbs, and now stuck with understanding Cassandra.

Lets say I have two models that have n fields same for both instances and m fields that differ.

```
{
    name:"Bob",
    surname:"Smith",
    age:31,
    carName: "toyota"
}

{
    name:"Ann",
    surname:"Cox",
    position:"Architect"
}
```

So here I have `name` and `surname` for both models, but other fields can be any fields.

Is it possible to design data table in Cassandra for such purpose or wide-column oriented databases not fit and better to use document oriented?

Comment: Have you looked into using a `Map`-typed column for the changing values?

Comment: @ernest_k yes but does `Map` support nesting? Lets say that we have a Car object under the 'car' field

Comment: No Cassandra's map (unlike DynamoDB for example) doesn't support nested. So you have two solutions: 1. You can store a serialized string (e.g., JSON) as the "car" field. The downside is that you can't directly modify nested properties, e.g., you can't do "SET car.model = 'something'".  Option 2: use the nested property names in the map's **key**. For example, "car.model" is the key. This way the nested structure is "flattened" on a non-nested map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fields are relative to the same “entity” then create a table with all of them and specify only relevant fields during inserts. Simple as that. Instead, if they are relative to a different entity then create two different tables.

Comment: This fields are relative to the entity, but they are not determined. Basically it can be any set of fields with any depth.